# I cannot get a where statement to work with server side script with mysql

Tags: datatables

I am doing a simple query with a where clause that looks for LIKE in a name with datables.

here is my structure

```
$lName = strtoupper($_GET['lname']);


// DB table to use
$table = 'alx80';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'casnum';

$whereResult = " WHERE  ptynam LIKE '%$lName%' ";

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the`dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'casnum', 'dt' => 'casnum' ),
array( 'db' => 'castyp',  'dt' => 'castyp' ),
array( 'db' => 'castds',   'dt' => 'castds' ),
array( 'db' => 'ptynam',     'dt' => 'ptynam' ),
array( 'db' => 'ptytyp',     'dt' => 'ptytyp' ),
array( 'db' => 'istat',     'dt' => 'istat' ),
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'kiju',
'pass' => 'jkiuju$hhg2',
'db'   => 'mysql',
'host' => 'localhost'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
* server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
*/

require( '../DataTables-1.10.5/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    //SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
SSP::complex ( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult )
);
```

When I run this i get this error

DataTables warning: table id=example - An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  ptynam = '%SMITH%' 
             ORDER BY `casnum` ASC
             LIMIT 0, 100' at line 3

Fine.

I've been trying to get the where to work, so I was using  //SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where ), and It work perfect. Except I couldn't search on data tables because I had already defined my where clause.

So my question is, how do I use data tables server side script with a where clause, and why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else having this problem, when you use the complex function you have to take the "WHERE" out of the $whereResult then it will work